# Draw shadow of layer-backed NSView beyond bounds

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nswindow, nsshadow

I'd like to get a custom NSShadow on a borderless NSWindow,
and since I'm also applying some animations on the window, I've set up the window's content view to be layer-backed.

When applying the NSShadow on the `contentView`, the shadow is clipped at the view's border:

[image]

One possibility would be to reduce `contentView`'s rect (*NSInsetRect*), but then the NSWindow's resizing borders wouldn't match the window's appearance!

Is there any chance to draw the layer's shadow beyond its borders?

**EDIT:** The shown screenshot already has a -10 inset rect!